# Joining Azure AD instead on prem creates new Windows profile?

Tags: active-directory, entra-id

I have a question about joining computers in my firm from on prem AD to Azure AD. When someone new arrives at our firm (new employee), there is a fresh installation of Windows 10. It is easy to join Azure AD because it is a fresh start, but now we have to migrate all Windows 10 users that are on prem AD to Azure AD. When I disconnect those users from our local on prem AD and join them to Azure AD, whole new Windows 10 profile is created, without any of settings, data or anything else on that profile (clean profile with few applications that are installed computer-wide). So my question is, is there any solution to keep their profile settings from before they joined Azure AD? Or I will have to simply tell them to backup everything (essential data).

What I tried so far:

- Tried tools for migration like ForensiT (User Profile Wizard, User Profile Manager and Transwiz, just to see if it is going to work) - not successful
- Tried changing profile path from registry - not successful
- Tried log in with the old credentials example: CONTOSO\user (because
  after I joined that computer to Azure AD user should log in as
  user@contoso.com) - not successful

Is there anything else I can try? Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, we can't login Azure AD account to new windows 10 with your original profile direct.

As a workaround, we can **redirect Documents folders to OneDrive with GPO**. In this way, we can sync users' profiles to OneDrive, then user login windows 10 with they Azure AD accounts, and install OneDrive App on it, they copy profile from OneDrive.

Here a article about redirect known folders to OneDrive for business, more information please refer to this [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Redirect-known-folders-to-OneDrive-for-Business-e1b3963c-7c6c-4694-9f2f-fb8005d9ef12?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

Hope this helpful.